jest.config.js not able to transfrom .ejs file
I get a configuration error inside my jest.config.js
Here is my jest.config.json
"use strict"

/** @type {import('jest').Config} */
const config = {
    verbose: true,
    moduleNameMapper: {
      "^.+\\ejs$": "./fileTransformer.js"
    },
    moduleFileExtensions: ["js", "jsx", "ejs", "ejx"],
    transform: {
      "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
      "^.+\\ejs$": "./fileTransformer.js"
    }
  };

module.exports = config

Here is my fileTransformer.js
const loader = require("ejs-loader")
module.exports = {process: loader}

Here is the error - pls see screenshot:

Can you please help me?

Remove moduleNameMapper config. This config is used for module alias, not for module transform.

Thank you for your reply! However - It did not fix the problem. I have a webpack config as well. Is this maybe a problem?
